# git checkout -b <branch> <sha> but not show history in git log

Tags: git

I accidentally delete my branch in git.
Then I recover branch by this command

```
git checkout -b <branch> < sha >
```

OK. It's recover my branch and branch is show again in git, but not show my commits  .It not restore my source code.

Comment: which <sha> are you using?  The one from the refs in the log file or a different one?

Comment: I found problem. I'm use not correct <sha>. After use correct <sha> I success restore not only branch but also last commit.